# Reaction rate constant conversion

Tags: kinetics, units

I'm flustered, I'm not into chemistry and need to convert $\mathrm{(nM\cdot s)^{-1}}$ to $\mathrm{(M\cdot s)^{-1}}$.
Is it correct to multiply with $10^9$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I am unsure what your question is supposed to be; turning nano-molar-seconds into mols? That doesn’t really make sense to me …

Comment: I'm designing a model of the EGFR pathway with simmune-software-tool and have to extract all kind of information from journals/papers about association rates and dissociation rates of the proteins in the pathway.

Comment: Wouldn't the conversion of *asssumed* nM into M imply *dividing* by $10^9$ instead of the multiplication mentioned in the OP?  Alternatively, a multiplication with $10^{-9}$ instead of $10^{9}$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a rate constant for a [second order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_reaction) reaction.  You want to convert from $(\mathrm{nM}^{-1} \cdot s^{-1})$ to $(\mathrm{M}^{-1} \cdot s^{-1})$.  So you have to write it out using fractions, like

$$ \mathrm{nM}^{-1} s^{-1}  = \frac{1}{\mathrm{nM} \cdot \mathrm{s}}\times \frac{10^9 \mathrm{nM}}{\mathrm{M}} = 10^9 \mathrm{M}^{-1} s^{-1}$$

So yes, you multiply the rate by $10^9$